# Facing problems while getting the records from the netsuite

Tags: c#, mysql, netsuite

I am trying to get the data from **Netsuite** through **Netsuite Ado.net driver** in **c#**.Table is created dynamically from code we wrote,but here the problem is binding ,we are unable to bind the data to the dynamically created table.Give some guide lines how to bind the data to the table.Please check the below code which i wrote...

```
public void inserting(string str1)
{
    string str = "data source=.;initial catalog=*****;Integrated security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
    SqlCommand cmd;

    string query = "select * from  " + str1;
    OpenAccessConnection connection = null;
    OpenAccessCommand command = null;
    OpenAccessDataReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        string connectionString = string.Format("Host=***********;Port=*******;ServerDatasource=******.co.in;User Id=mymailid;Password=********;EncryptionMethod=SSL;CustomProperties='AccountID=&&&&*****;RoleID=*'",
                                               Settings.Default.Host,
                                               Settings.Default.Port,
                                           Settings.Default.ServerDataSource,
                                               Settings.Default.Login,
                                               Settings.Default.Password,
                                               Settings.Default.AccountId,
                                               Settings.Default.RoleId);


        connection = new OpenAccessConnection(connectionString);
        command = new OpenAccessCommand(query, connection);
        connection.Open();
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
         DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
         con.Open();
        string str4 = CreateTABLE(str1, schemaTable);
        cmd = new SqlCommand(str4, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Label4.Visible = true;
        Label4.Text = "table created  sucessfully";

        while (reader.Read())
        {

          cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into account values ('" + reader[0].ToString() + "','" + reader[1].ToString() + "','" + reader[2].ToString() + "','" + reader[3].ToString() + "','" + reader[4].ToString() + "','" + reader[5].ToString() + "','" + reader[6].ToString() + "')", con);
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }         
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify: is your string.format call using the correct formatting pattern as specified in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx or is it exactly as written in your question?

Comment: Also note that your query could be susceptible to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Hii klitos,
          yes we need to give exactly like that as per i given above..!

Comment: Have you tried printing `connectionString`? You'll find that it contains asterisks, and the parameters you passed were not used.

Comment: connection string is fine,data is also comming from netsuite ,Here the problem is insertion while inserting data it shows some  columns are mismatched.Is there any alternative process for insertion without using insert command? like table to table replication from netsuite to local DB